# How do i overcome the cookie problem in InstaPy?

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, instagram, instapy

I'm trying to learn to code on InstaPy.

First, we started by using Selenium, which worked just fine.

Then, after installing InstaPy, things started to get hectic: apparently, instagram's cookies aren't universal and change from one country to another. Thus, the code that bypasses the cookie page is handling different problems the same way. And this is why I get this error:

> Cookie file not found, creating cookie...

I get this "accept cookies" page after logging in with InstaPy and then get this error mentioned before. If I click manually on "Accept All" it does work and continues the work flow.

So my problem here is how to bypass this problem: should I modify the code in the library? (I'm having a hard time understanding the whole coding of the InstaPy class, to be honest.)

Or should I try to do everything manually ?

```py
"""
This template is written by @loopypanda

What does this quickstart script aim to do?
- My settings is for running InstaPY 24/7 with approximately 1400
follows/day - 1400 unfollows/day running follow until reaches 7500 and than switch to unfollow until reaches 0.
"""

from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run

# get a session!
session = InstaPy(username=' ************ ', password=' **************** ', headless_browser= False)

# let's go! :>
with smart_run(session):
    # general settings

    # session.set_relationship_bounds(enabled=True,
    # delimit_by_numbers=False, max_followers=12000, max_following=4500,
    # min_followers=35, min_following=35)
    # session.set_user_interact(amount=2, randomize=True, percentage=100,
    # media='Photo')
    session.set_do_follow(enabled=True, percentage=100)
    session.set_do_like(enabled=True, percentage=100)
    # session.set_comments(["Cool", "Super!"])
    # session.set_do_comment(enabled=False, percentage=80)
    # session.set_user_interact(amount=2, randomize=True, percentage=100,
    # media='Photo')

    # activity

    # session.interact_user_followers(['user1', 'user2', 'user3'],
    # amount=8000, randomize=True)
    # session.follow_user_followers(['user1', 'user2', 'user3'],
    # amount=8000, randomize=False, interact=True)
    # session.unfollow_users(amount=7500, nonFollowers=True, style="RANDOM",
    # unfollow_after=42*60*60, sleep_delay=3)
    session.like_by_tags(['???'], amount=8000)

    """ Joining Engagement Pods...
    """
    photo_comments = ['Nice shot! @{}',
        'I love your profile! @{}',
        'Your feed is an inspiration :thumbsup:',
        'Just incredible :open_mouth:',
        'What camera did you use @{}?',
        'Love your posts @{}',
        'Looks awesome @{}',
        'Getting inspired by you @{}',
        ':raised_hands: Yes!',
        'I can feel your passion @{} :muscle:']
    session.set_do_comment(enabled = True, percentage = 95)
    session.set_comments(photo_comments, media = 'Photo')
    session.join_pods(topic='food')
```

Comment: I'm still trying to figure the answer for myself. Some interesting things to look at here https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/5886#issuecomment-727207957